# different database folder in EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to force EF 6 to create a sql server database in a specific folder rather than the standard folder in a code first scenario? I have done quite a few searches but could not find any useful information. Thanks.

PS:

connection string:

```
<add name="BlaDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1,1234;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Also tried to include DataDirectory and manipulate it from my console app as suggested by Steve Greene.

PPS:

Also tried:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
    @"  ALTER DATABASE [DB] MODIFY FILE 
        (
           Name = DB,
           Filename = 'D:\Databases\DB.mdf'
        );

        ALTER DATABASE [DB] MODIFY FILE 
        (
           Name = DB_log, 
           Filename = 'D:\Databases\DB_log.ldf'
        );
    ");
```

Comment: You mean localdb? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989371/can-i-specify-the-filename-for-a-localdb-database-in-entity-framework-5

Comment: No I mean a different folder than the default one

Comment: SQL Server? or some other database?

Comment: yes jjj. I have adapted my question.

Comment: do you...have a connection string?

Comment: thanks jjj - see PS.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the data folder:

```
// Set |DataDirectory| value
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "C:\MyFolder");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right, that is for localdb. If you are using SQL Server the easiest thing to do is go create the database where you want outside of EF and refer to it in your connection string. If that is not doable you would probably need to write a custom initializer http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2011/05/30/creating-a-code-first-database-initializer-strategy/ and include the SQL code to create the database where you want: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE xxx ON PRIMARY ( NAME = N'xxx', FILENAME = N'C:\MyPath\xxx.mdf') ...

Comment: Thanks I have written a custom initializer already. See PPS in my question, which shows a fraction. However, I do not think I can manipulate the CREATE DATABASE command of EF ... would love to though, if you know how.

Comment: Similar question here with a partial answer that you might be able to tweak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451738/ef-code-first-how-to-initialize-database-on-a-specific-location-hdd

Comment: Thanks Steve looks promising.