# EF Code First Database Physical Location

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have an application which used EF6 Code First with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializer.

Currently if the database doesn't exist EF will create a database located at the SQL Server default location.

Is there anyway to configure EF to create the database in another location. For example in the application data directory?

Comment: LocalDB or standard?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30452719/789571. Maybe, this could help you.

Comment: @jjj Express and above.

Comment: @MarcoHurtado I was looking for a simpler way which doesn't involve writing a Database Initializer from scratch but if it is the way it should be then I think this link will answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: You are using EF 6 and Code First.

1. Compile the project
2. Go to App.Config, look in section connectionStrings
3. Find the new "XYZEntities" entry, and look at the attribute "data source"
4. You should see this: (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB in the data source by default
5. To find the MDF file it uses, look at the attribute "attachdbfilename"
6. The physical file is stored by default in your documents folder.